# JQuery enable/disable input when right select value selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an input type `select` and input type `text`. What I want is that when I select on *"Others"* item in the select input, the other input type text will enable, if not it will be disabled. I have a code here, I probably miss something here.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var others = $('select[name="facility"]').val()
    $().ready(function() {
        if(others == "Others"){
            $('input').each(function() {

                if ($('#disabled_input').attr('disabled')) {
                    $('#disabled_input').removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                else {
                    $('#disabled_input').attr({
                        'disabled': 'disabled'
                    });
                }

            });
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `onchange` event to get the value of select and i assume `disabled_input` id is assigned to only one input field then there is no sense to loop through all the inputs

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#disabled_input').attr('disabled','disabled');        
$('select[name="facility"]').on('change',function(){
var  others = $(this).val();
    if(others == "Others"){           
    $('#disabled_input').removeAttr('disabled');          
     }else{
     $('#disabled_input').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }  

  });
});
</script>
```

### [See demo here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbwtq/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any need of `each` here.
For every iteration it will check `if ($('#disabled_input').attr('disabled'))`
which u can directly check

```
var others = $('select[name="facility"]').val();
 $(document).ready(function () {//missing document
     if (others == "Others") {
//no need of each here
         if ($('#disabled_input').attr('disabled')) {
         $('#disabled_input').removeAttr('disabled');
         } 
         else {
         $('#disabled_input').attr({'disabled': 'disabled'});  
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: @HarshdeepSokhey It was posted only 4 minutes after the accepted answer, and I don't think it was plagiarized.